# JAXWS vs. Apache CXF client considering thread safety?

Tags: java, web-services, thread-safety, jax-ws, cxf

I used to use the JAX-WS to generate client stubs. However, I learned recently that JAX-WS is not thread-safe and that Apache CXF is thread safe. I've read about it [here](http://cxf.apache.org/faq.html#FAQ-AreJAXWSclientproxiesthreadsafe?). Creating a new instance of proxy each time it is needed is not an options because the proxies takes a long time to create. Also, I have no background with Apache CXF.

- Which do you think is better when making client stubs considering the thread safety issue? Is it Apache CXF or JAX-WS? Why is it better?
- What are the differences and similarities of the 2 that I should consider?
- Should I use Apache CXF and give in to its thread safe feature instead of using JAX-WS? This is considering that the volume of users will most likely be hundreds of thousands.
- Other option that was suggested to me is to use JAX-WS and create a pool of proxies instead. I'm somewhat hesistant with this solution given the possible volume of users. Is this a good solution?
- Is there any other way to make the proxies in JAX-WS thread safe?

Comment: Too many questions encapsulated.

Comment: @subodh: I modified my question to make it more clear. Maybe my question will sum up to which of the 2 is better to use for clients considering that JAXWS is not thread-safe. The other questions are to make me understand the answer more.

Comment: see another answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136167/are-cxf-client-proxies-thread-safe)

Comment: @Ovidiu: Hi Ovidiu! Thanks for the link! I know CXF is thread-safe but my question is it is worth it to used CXF instead of JAXWS just to resolve the thread-safe issue? Or is there anything that can be done to make JAXWS thread-safe?

Comment: @Arci Sorry about the delay. As you know CXF is an implementation of JAX-WS so the thread-safety issue is much better addressed than you would address it in a short time.

Comment: @yohlulz: Thanks for your answer! Yes, I also realize that. I'm currently studying how to use CXF. Is there any significant difference in terms of performance if I use CXF instead of JAXWS? I'm just concern if CXF has any issue with its client since I'm not yet familiar of CXF.