# static method calling singleton

Tags: java, concurrency, cxf, static-methods

Consider this 'pattern' I encounter in a application I inherited:

```
public class BusinessUtil{
    public static void doBusiness(IService myService, String arg1, int arg2){
        //something something
        myService.doStuff(arg1, arg2);
    }
}
```

The *myService* bean is a springBean (=singleton). It is actually a cxf-client (=generated webservice-client)

This is in a webapplication, so the static *doBusiness()* method is called from different concurrent threads.
Is this method thread-safe?

Before you ask: I know this is a weird 'pattern'. I know the *doBusiness()* method is quite redundant since we can call *myService.doStuff()* directly instead of passing it into a static method, where it is called. As I said, I inherited an application where this 'pattern' is all over the place. I do not know why.
The application has (sometimes) some strange behaviour and I'm trying to locate the source of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in `doBusiness()` that make it thread-unsafe.  Whether it is thread safe or not depends on thread-safetiness of `myService.doStuff(arg1, arg2);`

Comment: thanks! Are there other considerations to make with this approach?
I mean, when would you use this approach: `BusinessUtil.doBusiness(service, arg1, arg2)` instead of the more intuitive `service.doStuff(arg1,arg2)`?
I ask because the 'pattern' I described in my question doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: well, to be honest such "pattern" doesn't seems making any sense to me either (if it is actually doing what you wrote).  However after working in development field for many years, I have seen a lot of people actually doing lots of "abstractions" or "pattern" that make no sense  :P

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's thread-safe or not depends on myService.doStuff(arg1, arg2); Since it is cxf-client this article [Are CXF client proxies thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136167/are-cxf-client-proxies-thread-safe)
may be useful

Comment: Thank you. I've seen the article. It is considered thread-safe for this use.